# Error loading GLEW library (error LNK2001)

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, glew

**I install GLEW library into the Visual Studio:**
x64/bin/glew32.dll to %SystemRoot%/system32
x64/lib/glew32.lib to {VC Root}/Lib
include/GL/glew.h to {VC Root}/Include/GL
include/GL/wglew.h to {VC Root}/Include/GL

**And add library in Linker > Input: glew32.lib and write #pragma comment**

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glut32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <glut.h>
```

But Visual Studio continues to write error:

```
1>Core.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewBindVertexArray
1>Core.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____glewGenVertexArrays
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing GLEW ([The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)). You can link this in with the following pragma somewhere in your source code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
```

Or you can modify the linker flags in the project settings. This assumes that you have the GLEW library installed. On my system, I installed it at the following path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/lib/glew32.lib
```

The path may be different on your system, and there are other ways of linking with GLEW if you don't want to install it.